# Rails 3 - increment_counter increments twice

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, model, increment

When I run this line of code

```
Movie.increment_counter :views, @moive.id
```

So the column **views** will be incremented twice (+2, not +1). In terminal I see this ran query to database:

```
UPDATE `movies` SET `views` = COALESCE(`views`, 0) + 1 WHERE `movies`.`id` = 8
```

If I attempt to run this query direct to MySQL, co the value of **views** is incremented correctly once (+1).

Any tips, what am I missing or I haven't set up?

Comment: in controller, I tried to put in into two else actions, but still the same

Comment: **:show**, ten also in **my_own_action**, and still the same

Answer (score 0):

Are you tracking page views by any chance? I ran into this as well- for every page load I would see the page view counter increment by three rather than 1, **but only in production**.

It turned out to be Google's Adsense code loading the page remotely. I noticed that they hit the page twice for every time one of my users would hit the page, effectively resulting in 3 page views. I suspect they do this to verify that content on the page meets their guidelines and to help match ads appropriately to page content. Check your httpd logs for `Mediapartners-Google`. I bet that's what's going on.

General advice: **use Google Analytics** (or similar service) for tracking page views. In my case I still needed to track this in a DB because I implement autocomplete based on "popularity" of certain page actions, but you might not need this.

Comment: I've seen similar redundant page loads under Rspec and Capybara.